# x86 assembler branching on a boolean stored in a register

Tags: assembly, x86

I know how to do the following if statement in assembly:

```
if(5 > 0){
  print("5 > 0");
 }



     mov $5, %ax
     mov $0, %bx
     cmp %ax, %bx
     jl t
     jge f
t: call print blah
     jmp next
f:  ...
next: ...
```

But I'm trying to do something like this in x86 assembler:

```
boolean x = 5 > 0;
if(x) {
 print("5 > 0");
}
```

How do I get the jmp conditions right when I store the relation operation result and use it later?

Comment: Consider the boolean as a byte: 0 meaning false, anything else meaning true

Comment: If you assign a value to a boolean in a higher level language, that doesn't necessarily prevent it from having to do an additional compare.  It's just that the second compare is looking at the value of the boolean (probably `test`ing it against zero) rather than the original args.  Which is basically what @BasileStarynkevitch was saying.

Comment: In your first example you can remove `jl t`. The `jge` will fall-trough to `t:` label in the "less" case any way, no need to have two jumps.